# ifconfig string comparrison

Tags: layout, configuration

I'm wondering if you can use Magento's ifconfig in layout xml for string comparrison?  Something like the below:

```
<action method="addCss" ifconfig="mdloptioncolor/genral_theme_setting/style_option==3"><stylesheet>'css/skyblue-color.css</stylesheet></action>
```

I've tried this but it does not work, is there a way of doing this?

Basically, instead of checking for a Boolean condition set by the user from the admin panel with a yes/no drop down, can check a for a string comparison in a drop down with multiple options

Answer (score 1):

This is checked for in class `Mage_Core_Model_Layout` and method `_generateAction()`.  At the top of this action you will see:

```
if (isset($node['ifconfig']) && ($configPath = (string)$node['ifconfig'])) {
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($configPath)) {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

So the value of `ifconfig` is cast to `(string)` and then fed to `Mage::getStoreConfigFlag()`.  This method is as follows:

```
public static function getStoreConfigFlag($path, $store = null)
{
    $flag = strtolower(self::getStoreConfig($path, $store));
    if (!empty($flag) && 'false' !== $flag) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So the string is just passed to the standard `Mage::getStoreConfig()` method and if the returned value is not empty and is not the string `false` then `true` is returned.  In all other cases `false` is returned in which case further processing of the action method is halted.

So the long and short of it is no, you can't do any kind of string comparison inside `ifconfig` however you could **rewrite** and extend the `getStoreConfigFlag()` to consider the returned value from `getStoreConfig()`, for instance the following would add string comparison:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Layout extends Mage_Core_Model_Layout
{
    private $_configvalue;

    protected function _generateAction($node, $parent)
    {
        if (isset($node['ifconfig']) && ($path = (string) $node['ifconfig'])):
            if ($path = $this->_getCompareValue($path)):
                $value = Mage::getStoreConfig($path);
                if (!empty($value) && $value == $this->_configvalue):
                    return true;
                endif;

                return false;
            endif;
        endif;

        return parent::_generateAction($node, $parent);
    }

    private function _getCompareValue($path)
    {
        $this->_configvalue = false;
        if (strpos($path, '=') !== false):
            $array = explode('=', $path);
            $value = end($array);
            if (!empty($value)):
                $this->_configvalue = $value;

                return reset($array);
            endif;
        endif;

        return false;
    }
```